# Appsflyer cordova-plugin-appsflyer-sdk - unable to track installations on Android

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk, appsflyer-cordova-sdk

I am using a Cordova plugin to track installations of my hybrid Apps: [cordova-plugin-appsflyer-sdk](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/cordova-plugin-appsflyer-sdk).

This plugin works for me on iOS, I am able to track installations of the iOS App built with Cordova. I am unable though to track the installations of the Android app.

When I use their [Integration Test App](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/210213753-Additional-Testing-for-AppsFlyer-Android-SDK) I get this error:

[image]

The [dashboard](https://hq1.appsflyer.com/) is configured in this way:

I clicked "Add App", I chose "Android out of store APK", I added as store details: the bundle identifier of my app, "TEST" as channel name and a fake url for the App URL. 
I saved and the dashboard got created successfully.

When I execute the [initSdk command](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/cordova-plugin-appsflyer-sdk/blob/master/docs/API.md#initSdk) the response says "success" but no installations appear on the dashboard!

Logs in console:
[image]

Comment: **I will give a 100 bounty to who will able to help me in a timely matter, thanks!**

Comment: ```I clicked "Add App", I chose "Android out of store APK"``` - This is probably the issue.

You should select `Pending Approval Or Unpublished`, select the Google Play toggle and input the package name of your application (as defined for Android, e.g. `com.appsflyer.analytics`)

Selecting `Out of Store` requires an additional appendix to your package name, and you probably don't want that.

Comment: @BenjaminAF It worked!! Thanks!! Create and answer and I'll mark it as chosen reply and give you the bounty in 2 days.